# nagis cache remote website

Tags: unix, caching, nginx

i had installe nginx on my local machine,
my problem is i would like to do a cache for my website .
help to configure nginx

this my configuration

server
{
    server_name .mywebsite.com;

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

root /var/www/example.com/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

# use fastcgi for all php files
location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to apache .htaccess files
location ~ /\.ht
{
    deny all;
}
```

}

but i dosen't had any static content on my local machine

help please best regards

Comment: Please read the manual. http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration